# Как правильно сделать emplace_back

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Конструктор `stype` выделяет память, если через `push_back` то удаляется деструктором это понятно, `emplace` - не может понять что за тип(?), приходится дописывать `emplace_back(stype({..,..}))` и из-за этого думаю вызывается 2 раза оператор `stype(stype& s)` и деструктор..

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct variant
{
    size_t size;
    void* p;
    variant(variant& v) {
        p = new char[v.size];//этого не надо, и вообще этот оператор
        size = v.size, memcpy(p, v.p, size);
    }
    template<typename T>
    variant(T v) {
        p = new T(v);
        size = sizeof(T);
    }
    template<typename T>
    operator T&() {
        return *(T*)p;
    }
    template<typename T>
    T operator->() const { return *(T*)p; }
    ~variant() {
        delete p;
    }
};

typedef enum { GUMBO_TAG_HTML, GUMBO_TAG_HEAD } GumboTag;
class tlist
{
public:
    int axis;
    variant node;
};

GumboTag f()
{
    return GUMBO_TAG_HEAD;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::vector<tlist> tl;
    int axis = 0;
//  tl.push_back({ axis, f() });//работает без tlist()
    tl.emplace_back(tlist({ axis, f() }));
    std::cout << static_cast<GumboTag>(tl[0].node);
}
```

<del>можно заодно спросить как это лучше сделать, boost::variant не понимает enum почему то, any тоже не понравился (не помню уже чем, типы чтоли пришлось бы хранить отдельно :)</del>

```
struct tlist
{
    int axis;
    variant node;
    template<typename T>
    tlist(int a, T n) : axis(a), node(n) {}
};
```

Вот так вроде работает как надо:), как и думал, темплатизировать tlist конструктор (еще не проверил в основной программе).

Comment: А что не работает-то? http://ideone.com/jKd8iB - что тут не так?

Comment: А вы не можете дать минимальный пример? Который бы компилировался с указанием вашего типа в `emplace`, а без него - нет? Пытаться дорабатывать ваш до компилируемого состояния напильником - слишком тяжелая задача...

Comment: Ну извините уж... Будет [минимальный пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - буду смотреть, а так уступаю место более просвещенным товарищам :)

Comment: компилятор какой?

Comment: @ixSci - vs2015, на другом компиляторе получилось так: http://ideone.com/DLEshF

Comment: кажется мне надо конструктор tlist темплатизировать?

Comment: Гляньте дополнение к моему ответу.

Answer (score 1):

VC++ 2015 "все соображает, все понимает..." (с) :)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

struct stype
{
    stype(stype&& s):ptr(s.ptr) { s.ptr = 0; cout << "stype(const stype&&)\n"; }
    stype(const stype& s):ptr(s.ptr) { cout << "stype(const stype&)\n"; }
    ~stype(){ cout << "~stype()\n"; }
    void* ptr;
    template<typename T>
    stype(T v) { ptr = new T(v); 
        cout << "stype(" << typeid(v).name() << "  " << v << ")\n"; }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<stype> v;
    v.reserve(10);
    v.emplace_back(5);
    v.emplace_back(3.6);
    v.emplace_back(4.1f);
    v.emplace_back("Hello");
}
```

не дает ничего лишнего:

```
stype(int  5)
stype(double  3.6)
stype(float  4.1)
stype(char const *  Hello)
~stype()
~stype()
~stype()
~stype()
```

Так что - если можно, поясните, в чем все же проблема?

**Update**

Стоит сделать так:

```
class tlist
{
public:
    tlist(int a, variant n):axis(a),node(n){}
...

tl.emplace_back(axis, f());
```

как все работает...

Comment: результат тот же..), может быть нет разницы emplace или push?, даже push меньше на 1 цикл копирований, не понятно, и еще как {list} работает у push и не работает у emplace

Comment: `push` получает объект - соответственно, он его создает из переданных аргументов, как если бы было вызвано `push_back(tlist(...));` А `emplace` - вещь вариадически-шаблонная, и ей нужны параметры для конструктора поодиночке.

Comment: Кстати, вот минимальный пример:   `std::vector<int> il; il.emplace_back({2});`

Comment: у меня не работает это=) (пример). обычное int(не лист) emplace создает как и написано прямо на месте, я уже с move и отдельно на части разбивая пробовал. В любых случаях он создает variant, создает 2 раза tlist копирует во 2-й var и удаляет

Comment: См. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/595871/emplace-back-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-int