# emplace_back для int

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++

*‒ Ты понимаешь, что происходит?*
*‒ Тебе объяснить?*
*‒ Объяснить я и сам могу... Ты понимаешь или нет?*

Простите за эпиграф, но... Что-то у меня ощущение, что я могу объяснить, но не понимаю (или наоборот...), что происходит вот тут:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.emplace_back(1);
v.emplace_back({1});
v.emplace_back(int{1});
```

Как стандарт трактует эти три выражения, и почему такой странный диагноз

> emplace_back: функция не принимает 1 аргументов

у средней строки?

Comment: Так компилятор же [всё пишет](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/52Vx4kBzhMoktzWT). Это `initializer-list`, который не может быть преобразован в `int`.

Comment: С другой стороны, не всё так [гладко](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/5hDzw2WxMR3ZMJBV).

Comment: Некое подобие ответа [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24550924/3240681).

Comment: Ну а что необычного? У средней строки тип `initializer_list`, а у двух других `int` https://godbolt.org/g/YMgcA5

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Для этого предложения

```
v.emplace_back({1});
```

проблема состоит в том, что когда используются шаблонные параметры, то не выводится тип  шаблонного параметра из заключенного в фигурные скобки аргумента. А функция `emplace_back` использует шаблонные параметы.

Из стандарта C++ (14.8.2.1 Deducing template arguments from a function call)

> 1 Template argument deduction is done by comparing each function
>   template parameter type (call it P) with the type of the corresponding
>   argument of the call (call it A) as described below. If removing
>   references and cv-qualifiers from P gives std::initializer_list
>   for some P0 and the argument is an initializer list (8.5.4), then
>   deduction is performed instead for each element of the initializer
>   list, taking P0 as a function template parameter type and the
>   initializer element as its argument. **Otherwise, an initializer list
>   argument causes the parameter to be considered a non-deduced context**

Можно смоделировать такую же ошибку следующим примером объявления класса

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

struct A
{
    template <typename ...T>
    void f( T &&... ) const {}
};

int main() 
{
    A().f( { 1 } );

    return 0;
}
```

Компилятор может выдать следующее диагностическое сообщение

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:13:15: error: no matching function for call to 'A::f(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
  A().f( { 1 } );
               ^
prog.cpp:8:7: note: candidate: void A::f(T&& ...) const [with T = {}]
  void f( T &&... ) const {}
       ^
prog.cpp:8:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

Если вы замените `emplace_back` на нешаблонный метод `push_back` , то соответствующий вызов будет компилироваться, так как тип параметра функции известен из типа объявленного инстанциированного вектора и представляет собой тип `int`.

Поэтому вам явно нужно будет указать тип шаблонного аргумента функции

Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

struct A
{
    template <typename ...T>
    void f( T &&... ) const {}
};

int main() 
{
    A().f<int>( { 1 } );

    return 0;
}
```

Или для `emplace_back`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v;

    v.emplace_back<int>( { 1 } );

    for ( int x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
1
```

или для примера, предложенного **@alexolut** в комментарии

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct S 
{
    S(std::initializer_list<int>) {}
};

int main() 
{
    std::vector<S> v;
    v.emplace_back<std::initializer_list<int>>({1});
}
```

Что касается выражения в данном вызове

```
v.emplace_back(int{1});
```

то здесь используется явное преобразование типов, так называемая функциональная нотация.

Из стандарта C++ (5.2.3 Explicit type conversion (functional notation))

> 3 Similarly, a simple-type-specifier or typename-specifier followed by
>   a braced-init-list creates a temporary object of the specified type
>   direct-list-initialized (8.5.4) with the specified braced-init-list,
>   and its value is that temporary object as a prvalue.

Comment: Как Вы прокомментируете [эту ситуацию](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/5hDzw2WxMR3ZMJBV)?

Comment: То есть если я напишу для своего класса конструктор от `initializer_list`, то это не спасает, потому что этот тип не выводится? (понятно, что я уже пробовал писать :)) Но как тогда компилятор воспринимает - что это там такое лежит `{1}` - в средней строчке? Какой-то тип эта запись имеет?

Comment: Да, я это делал, в смысле - проверял для нешаблонной `push_back`. Тут вроде понятно - при конструкторе не explicit для пользовательского класса выполняется преобразование через промежуточный тип... Интересно, почему при шаблонном параметре тип initializer_list не выводится - потому что сам шаблон?

Comment: @Harry Я сейчас пока удалю свой ответ и займусь чтением стандарта.:)

Comment: @Harry Я привел цитату из стандарта в отношении этой проблемы.

Comment: @alexolut Смотрите мой обновленный ответ.

Comment: @Harry, эта запись никакого типа не имеет, она ill-formed.